# Macbook Air touchpad not working on Void Linux

Tags: touchpad, void-linux

I have installed Void Linux musl base system on a 2017 Macbook Air, but the touchpad is not working.

How to make the touchpad work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terminal (with super user privileges), use

```bash
modprobe -r usbmouse
modprobe -r bcm5974
modprobe bcm5974
```

Optionally put these lines to `/etc/rc.local` to persist over reboots.